# Font where 6 is different from upside down 9

Tags: fonts

Can you suggest a font where a `6` is different from an upside down `9`?

It doesn't have to be the font itself that creates the diffence; if you can come up with a smart solution for an upside down `9` not looking like a `6`, I will be glad to hear about it.

Comment: See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71209/looking-for-font-where-6-is-very-different-from-upside-down-9

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm not sure if this answers my question. I think it only tells me that they haven't found a good solution. (I might be wrong.) Can you come up with a solution to my problem?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it was exactly an answer. Looking through my fonts it seems that the only ones that have distinct 9s and 6s are handwriting style or super super stylized. So if that's not a solution, then mangling an existing font's glyphs seems to be the only other option, or adding an under or over macron to the 6s and/or 9s.  If that's a possibility, it could be automated in XeLaTeX using char classes or a Teckit mapping file.

Comment: Close, but distinct: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/firasansnewtxsf/

Comment: I'll underline `6` and `9` instead, I think. Thank you both!

Comment: Just as an afterthought, underlining is standard for 6 and 9 in, for example, games in which numbers appear alone on game tiles.

Comment: Whoever is voting to close: although font requests *per se* are off topic, Svend has also asked for an alternative solution, which is perfectly on topic, so I don't think this question should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most fonts that have distinct 6 and 9 glyphs are very stylized or handwriting style. If that's not acceptable, then you could use a combining undermacron with an OpenType font to make 6s and 9s distinct. You can enter this directly into your source or use a macro.  If you need this a lot, then a Teckit mapping approach might be useful.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newcommand{\SN}[1]{{\fontspec{#1} #1: 6 and 9}}
\newfontfamily\LLO[Mapping=6and9]{Linux Libertine O}
\newcommand{\six}{6\symbol{"0331}}
\newcommand{\nine}{9\symbol{"0331}}
\begin{document}
\Large
\SN{Bradley Hand Bold}

\SN{Brush Script Std}

\SN{Chalkduster}

\SN{Giddyup Std}

Combining undermacron in source approach: 6̱ and 9̱

Macro approach: \six\ and \nine

Automatic using Teckit mapping: {\LLO 6 and 9}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### `6and9.map` file

```
LHSName "plain"
RHSName "underlined"
pass(Unicode)
"6" > "6̱" 
"9" > "9̱"
; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question
```

Compile to a `.tec` file using `teckit_compile -u  6and9.map -o 6and9.tec`.